# Unable to share Image using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, uri, share, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am able to share on Facebook using the function below if I remove this like "**.setImageUrl(imgToShare)**"

My package name is correct when building `imgToShare` and also `R.drawable.ic_launcher` definitely exists.

What could be the issue here? I just want to share an image from my drawable folder.

```
public final void launchFacebook() {
    Uri imgToShare = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mypackage.name/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("FocusON")
                .setContentDescription(
                        "Text to post to facebook")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.myurl.com"))
                .setImageUrl(ResourceToUri(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setImageUrl(imgToShare)
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like sharing photos on Facebook works a little different than sharing links. I haven't tested the following, but after reading their docs I think it should be something like this:

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().
        .setImageUrl(imageToShare)
        .setCaption("text to post to facebook")
        .build();

SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
        .addPhoto(photo)
        .build();

shareDialog.show(content);
```

**Refs**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#photos